# How to force recheck user with reCAPTCHA?

Tags: recaptcha

I use reCAPTCHA in our registration form. In some instances, I want to force the user to have to recomplete reCAPTCHA. I know I can use `grecaptcha.reset();` to reset the reCAPTCHA. My question is, is there a similar command to tell Google this is a high risk user and to force the user to recomplete CAPTCHA (maybe with stronger CAPTCHA), not just simply reset the CAPTCHA?