# How to implement choose squares with street signs reCAPTCHA

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha, captcha

I am making a website form and I would like to be able to use the type of reCAPTCHA where you select all the squares on an image, which contain a certain item (like a street sign). However, it doesn't explain it on google's documentation. This is how you would go about implementing a checkbox reCAPTCHA iN HTML:

```
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Simple page</title>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was wondering if you have to modify this in any way in order to get the image reCAPTCHA, or if there is a completely different piece of code I would have to implement.

Comment: AFAIK that's ReCaptcha v2, in case you're using v3, and it only shows you the classification challenge if it doesn't already trust you. (Incognito mode usually gets the images for me if you just want to test it.) If ReCaptcha is already happy with the user do you need to force it?

Comment: I do need to force it though

Comment: Here's an old question asking the same thing, with no answers alas: [Force Google Recaptcha Challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431361/force-google-recaptcha-challenge)