# Force Google invisible Recaptcha Challenge

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, react-google-recaptcha

I have to implement google invisible recaptcha on my website login page, the scenario is recaptcha challenge(image grid) should be displayed if the user login attempt is more than 5 times, but invisible captcha does not show the image grid, it shows very rarely.

I found that using explicit rendering + immediately calling grecaptcha.execute() after grecaptcha.render() will usually trigger the challenge from this link [Force google recaptcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431361/force-google-recaptcha-challenge), I tried like this, as our login happens thorugh ajax call when I render again getting "recaptcha already rendered on this element". Is there any other possible way to force the recaptcha challenge? Anaswers are much appreciated

```
  if(typeof widget1 !== 'undefined') {
    grecaptcha.reset(widget1);
}

widget1 = grecaptcha.render('test', {
    'sitekey' : '6LdmI_0UAAAAABMAMmt7sGWV5v9JZMSeZbW9CVPs',
    'callback' : onSuccessfullCaptchaVerification,
    'size' : 'invisible'
});
console.log('success!');
grecaptcha.execute(widget1);
```